# Why I can't insert " " to cancel "FALSE" text in this formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

This is the formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1; "Time"; if(len(A:A); IF(C:C=F:F;
    IF(QUOTIENT(F:F*(D:D/60);24)<1;
        ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24))& IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24)>1);" ore"; " ora")&" circa";
        QUOTIENT(F:F*(D:D/60);24) & IF(QUOTIENT(F:F*(D:D/60);24)>1;" giorni";" giorno") & IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24)=0);""; " e "&ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24))&" ore"&" circa"));
    IF(QUOTIENT(F:F*(D:D/60);24)<1;
        ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24))&IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24)>1);" ore"; " ora")&" circa"&"<br>su "&ROUNDUP(MOD(C:C*(D:D/60);24))&" ore"&" circa";
        QUOTIENT(F:F*(D:D/60);24)& IF(QUOTIENT(F:F*(D:D/60);24)>1;" giorni";" giorno")&" e "& IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24)=0);""; ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24))&IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(F:F*(D:D/60);24)>1);" ore"; " ora")&" circa")&"<br>su "&QUOTIENT(C:C*(D:D/60);24)& IF(QUOTIENT(C:C*(D:D/60);24)>1;" giorni";" giorno")& IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(C:C*(D:D/60);24)=0);""; " e "&ROUNDUP(MOD(C:C*(D:D/60);24))&" ore"&" circa"))))))
```

Here an example sheet with the formula in action:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zP2i-Tx3QKEZjU4SbiyJg4xWwtTZt9seDDzSrRxlOjg/

Why I can't insert "" at the end of the formula for eliminate the "FALSE" text in the rows under the last row with content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try replacing the last six closing parentheses with:

```
))),"")))
```